# JQuery 2.0.3, hide all divs at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is a code snippet where we always animate one `<div>` and `hide()` the rest. This produces a long list of `hide()` as we add more.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
            function showSlidingDivVideoCategory(){
                // show what we need
                $("#slidingDivVideoCategory").animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 500 });

                // hide what we dont
                $("#slidingDivAudioCategory").hide();
                $("#slidingDivPicturesCategory").hide();
                $("#slidingDivAdsCategory").hide();
                $("#slidingDivMediaRoom").hide();
                $("#slidingDivKeynotePresentations").hide();
                $("#slidingDivBlog").hide();
                $("#slidingDivAbout").hide();
                $("#slidingDivSubmitFootage").hide();
                $("#slidingDivContact").hide();
                $("#slidingDivSearchBox").hide();
```

Is there a way that I can `hide()` all `<div>` so I can just then show the few I want and `animate` the one I want?

Comment: Give them a common class! There is no needs to list every single element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look you can use advance selectors, I saw you have many ids starting by the same word so this would work

```
$("[id*=slidingDiv]").hide();

//For the animate use what you have
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: Starting-with would be `[id^="slidingDiv"]`, `[id*="slidingDiv"]` selects any element with an `id` that merely *contains* the string `'slidingDiv'` (which may, or may not, be what the OP would need).

Comment: It gives the same result

Comment: Absolutely; right up until there's an element with `id="unslidingDiv"` that, probably, *shouldn't* be selected, anyway.

Comment: `[id^="slidingDiv"]` works as does `[id*="slidingDiv"]` given my circumstance.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the individual hide statements and use:

```
$("div:not('#slidingDivVideoCategory')").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to hide **all** `<div>`s, use

```
$('div').hide();
```

However, you might want to add a class to all `<div>`s you want to be hidden add use

```
$('.yourclassname').hide();
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class selector and hide using class.

```
$(".myclass").hide();
```

Or combine multiple selectors:

```
$("#slidingDivAudioCategory, #slidingDivPicturesCategory, #slidingDivsAdsCategory").hide();
```